# Problem in solving a question related to Lorentz transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Let $(x, t)$ and $(x', t')$   be the coordinate system used by the observers $O$ and $O'$. Let O' move with velocity v=Bc along their common positive x axis. If X+=x+ct and X-=x-ct are the linear combinations of the coordinates,
Write down expressions of X+' as function of f(X+, B)  and X-' as function of f(X-, B).
Here c is the speed of light.